# angular 6 to 8, angular universal, An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I try to upgrade the angular version and re-establish the new version of `angular universal`.

Angular universal insatall:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject [project name]
```

Bulid project

```
npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr
```

package.json

```
"serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
"build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run [project name]:server:production",
```

Error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace.
```

I [tried](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12290) removing the `--prod` command but it still doesn't work

Below is my `angular.json` file:

`[project-name]`: my project name.

`[a sequence]`: a sequence of automatically generated sequences.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "[project-name]": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/csspin/csspin.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "[project-name]:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "[project-name]:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "[project-name]:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "[project-name]:build",
            "serverTarget": "[project-name]:server"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "[project-name]:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "[project-name]:server:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "[project-name]:build:production",
            "serverTarget": "[project-name]:server:production",
            "routes": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {}
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "[project-name]-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "[project-name]:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "[project-name]:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "[project-name]",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "[a sequence]"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have no "production" section under "server". Did you misplace your "production" config under "serve" <-- no "r" at the end.